# ViewWillDisappear is not calling when removing the sub view from super view

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, subview, swift5

ViewWillDisappear is not called when removing the subviews from the superview in the tabBarViewController.

Here, I am sharing code to understand, how I am removing the subviews.

```
 AppDelegate.sharedApp().window?.subviews.forEach({ (view) in
     view.removeFromSuperview()
 })

 AppDelegate.sharedApp().window?.rootViewController = viewController
 AppDelegate.sharedApp().window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In tabBarViewController viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear is not calling.
Please help me how to make a call to viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear in the above scenario.
Thank you.

Here, sharing the tabBarViewController code too,

```
class MyTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataCheck"), object: nil)
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataCheck"), object: nil)
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    }

    @objc func checkData() {

    }

}
```

When removing the subview at that time I should unregister the added observers to this view controller.

Comment: viewWillDisappear have you write super.viewWillDisappear ?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried with super.viewWillDisappear but still the same issue persists.

Comment: Where is this code snippet you shared located? Inside some method of a ViewController?

Comment: I you are manually removing views from their superviews the view life cycle methods are not called on the viewcontroller's owning the views.

Comment: Hello Rohan Bhale, I have edited the question, please check one. If view life cycles are not calling, is there any other solution for this type of scenarios. I have tried with deinit also. still, deinit also not  getting called in tabBarViewController.

Comment: @matt Whenever i am removing the subviews from superview I need to unregister the registered observers from that view.I am trying to unregister those in viewWillDisappear but those methods are not getting called.

Comment: @matt Not only Notification Centre, I also have timers running in that view controller and if I do not invalidate the timers I am seeing memory leaks which is causing app to crash.

Comment: I have tried with `deinit` also but `deinit` is also not getiing called.

Comment: Yes, because you have a retain cycle. But that is the real problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 2):

`viewWillDisappear` is not called if you forcibly tear down the entire view controller hierarchy by replacing the window's root view controller:

```
 AppDelegate.sharedApp().window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

You should not be doing that. But if you *are* going to do that, there is no surprise that `viewWillDisappear` is not called.

But now let us ask what you needed `viewWillDisappear` for. You do not need to call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` in modern iOS, so the example is meaningless.

Moreover, when you say

```
 AppDelegate.sharedApp().window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

any existing view controllers should go out of existence and their `deinit` will be called. You can use this as a signal that the view controller is being torn down, if you need one.

If your `deinit` is *not* being called, that is a sign that you have a retain cycle. But then *that* is the problem you need to fix. Your question does not give any information about that, so it's impossible to help in detail.

Just to give an example, a Timer is often a cause of a retain cycle. But this is easily fixed: instead of calling

```
scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)
```

you call

```
scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)
```

and use `[weak self]` in the `block`.

Answer (score 0):

just give the delegate to that view of your super view controller and then ViewWillDisappear will work as passing delegate of self give it presence to subView.